# Custom handler not getting called

Tags: asp.net

web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add type="WebApplicationModulesAndHandlers.WebApplicationModulesAndHandlers.CspxHandler, WebApplicationModulesAndHandlers" verb="*" path="*.cspx" validate="true"/>
</httpHandlers>

public class CspxHandler :IHttpHandler
{
    public CspxHandler()
    {

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        if (context.Request.RawUrl.Contains(".cspx"))
        {
            string newUrl = context.Request.RawUrl.Replace(".cspx", ".aspx");
            context.Server.Transfer(newUrl);
        }        
    }

}
```

I have a handler that implements IHttpHandler.
I am using asp.net 4.5.1 application
When I browse to a page like Default.cspx, it says page doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Issue is resolved. I was specifying AssemblyName.Namespace.IHttpHandler.
All I had to do was remove the assemblyname

Answer (score 0):

Check your project -> property-> web
if you are using local iis web server, you probably need register you new file extension to let it be able to forwarded to .net.